# PHP controlling LED through a script. Can't get it to work

Tags: gpio, python, php

I have made a very small script for my Raspberry Pi where I turn on the LED.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(21,1)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(21,0)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The script works I checked it with `sudo python led.py`

I'm using apache server on my rapberry pi.
Python version is 2.7.3

index.php:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['on'])){
                echo "on"
                exec('sudo python /var/www/led.py');
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['off'])){
                echo "off";
        }
?>
<html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
                <form method="get">
                        <button name="on">on</button><br>
                        <button name="off">on</button><br>
                </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

I tried with `echo exec(whoami);`

Answer (score 2):

It is all to do with permissions.

The scipt works locally because it is run as the (presumably) `pi` user.  The `pi` user has (passwordless) access to the `sudo` command to run programs as `root`.  The RPi.GPIO module requires to be run as `root`.

It fails in your script because it runs as the (Apache) `www-data` user.  The `www-data` user in not a member of `sudoers` so can not run `sudo`.  Thus the RPi.GPIO script fails as you don't have root access.

There are ways around this but all the ones I know of are pretty insecure and will compromise the security of your Pi.

Comment: I only use my pi on my own network... Do you know another method for enabling remote controk

Comment: @GProduct Google will reveal dozens of ways depending on how heavyweight a solution you want.  Personally I use my own [pigpio Python](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module as scripts run as an ordinary user (no sudo required) and communicate with a daemon which runs as root.

Comment: Okay I'm gonna take a look at it